# How to use only server datetime and ignore client datetime?

Tags: momentjs

I'm using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) to manipulate with datetimes. My problem is machine of client datetime. If client changes date in his machine it affect in application too. Example:

```
this.from = moment.utc(this.test.from).valueOf();
this.to = moment.utc(this.test.to).valueOf();
```

Those variables will change if client change datetime in his machine! Can I stop this somehow?

**P.S. Result of valueOf is same with or without using utc!**

Comment: The time is probably the same and the client machine's time zone has been changed.

Comment: I'm trying by myself, if I change date valueOf() with changes too! Even if this.test.from is constant and comes form backend